# Show at which date a bounty was started

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I don't know if it's just me, but I just stumbled over [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821917/why-doesnt-my-script-tag-work-from-php-file-jquery-involved-here-too) [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php) on SO, which, at first glance, looked like bugs to me. The questions, the bounties were offered for, are dated back to year 2009.

The block

> This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from User ending in 6 days.

below the question made me think "Wow, a bounty running for nearly 2 years?! Is this a bug?".

Without searching the SO FAQ and *finding* the [setting bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) entry (which is somewhat hidden within the "What if I don't get a good answer" block), I still wouldn't know that bounties (at least on SO) always expire after 7 days.

Hence, I still would think of bugs (and probably "I guess there won't be much users willing/motivated to answer bounties running for such a long time...").

Wouldn't it be better to show the bounties starting date somewhere (e.g. in the bounty block below the question) to avoid such kind of misinterpretation/irritation?

I mean s/t like this

> This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from User
>   ending in 6 days (bounty started at YYYY-MM-DD).

or

> This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from User, started 1 day ago, 
>   ending in 6 days.

or whatever would help right away.

Comment: I think there's one of two solutions here.  a) increase awareness of how the bounty works (you stated yourself you had problems finding it) or b) what you propose above.  I don't have a problem with the above, although some might think it adds noise.  If it doesn't add noise, then I'm all for it.

Comment: @casperOne: yeah, a) would be good, too. I somehow managed to miss that bounty tooltip for more than a half year... ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your mouse above the bounty expire time (e.g. "6 days" in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441496/session-lost-when-switching-from-http-to-https-in-php)), then you'll see the tooltip with exact timestamps.

[image]

Note that it's perfectly valid to put bounties on old questions.

Comment: Argl, missed that one too, thank you.

Comment: @Chichiray: It answers the question, but I think that it's one of those "easter egg" kind of things.  I think better visibility in *some* area is required.

Answer (score 4):

It actually does tell you when it started, but you have to be a bit intentional about it:

[image: bounty time tooltip, a bird's eye view]

The bounty information is also available in the [question history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/441496/revisions). Arguably both of these locations are a bit out of the way, but the relative time tooltip displaying the specific time information is a pretty common convention on the site.

Comment: I wasn't that intentional, I guess. Thanks for pointing out the question history. Missed that one too, my bad.

Comment: I don't know how you expect to get upvotes without a bird in your screenshot

Comment: I would've upvoted him except there was a bird in his screenshot.

Comment: +1 for the freehand bird.

Comment: Hmm, competition :(

Comment: @Chichiray Not really, your self-photo is still far more impressive, I must admit.

Comment: My bird? I don't have one. I am the one!

Comment: @Chichiray Fixed!