# Triggering the "X time ago" on bounties

Tags: feature-request, bounties, timestamps

At this point:

[image]

The question appears as if nothing had changed (good thing, since it actually didn't). But for the ones obsessed (like me) on knowing the whole history of posts, it is a bit counter intuitive to have a blank post without a link to *revisions*, but that have had important details in the revisions.

I don't want to go randomly accessing the revisions by typing the url, this will be slow and unhealthy. It would be handy to have messages like this:

[image]

And the same when bounty period have concluded or awarded on answers.

Comment: What import details are in the revision here, exactly? The bounty [tells you when it started](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111835/show-at-which-date-a-bounty-was-started), if you're really interested in that. I don't see anything overly wrong with adding the link, but I'm not sure it's very useful in the general case.

Comment: It is mainly just for consistency, everything that adds a revision entry creates the "X time ago" message with the exception of bounties. But I think there should be no exception, if the revision is not empty, so should the link to revision.